# Open Password Protected Excel File using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write some VBA that opens an excel file, **enters password, readonly = no,** then runs my macro, saves, closes...

I have everything working great, except for the "password" piece.  I cannot get this VBA to do the VBA piece properly!!!

(Password for this example is "pw")

---

```
Dim objExcel

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

objExcel.workbooks.open("C:\users\bal01483\desktop\vb\book2.xlsm")     **'(PLEASE HELP ME FIGURE OUT THE PASSWORD PIECE.)**

objExcel.Visible = True

objExcel.Run "helloworld"

objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Save

objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close(0)

objExcel.Quit
```

Comment: there is a password parameter in ```workbooks.open```. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbooks.open

Comment: Dim objExcel

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\users\bal01483\desktop\vb\book2.xlsm", ReadOnly:=False, Password:="pw", WriteResPassword:="pw", ignorereadonlyrecommended:=True
objExcel.Visible = True
objExcel.Run "helloworld"
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Save
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close(0)
objExcel.Quit